# Is it possible to express "$x$" in this equation using only "$a$"?

Tags: problem-solving, cubics

I have following equations:

$$\frac{(x-1)}{(a-1)}=\frac{(y-1)}{(b-1)}$$
$$\frac{(y-1)}{(b-1)}=\frac{(z-1)}{(c-1)}$$

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} = k$$

$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = 1$$

I need to solve by $x$ from this equation where $(x,y,z,a,b,c,k \in \mathbb{R})$, and the best I can get is this:

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{(x - 1) (b - 1)}{a - 1} + 1} + 
  \frac{1}{\frac{(x - 1) (c - 1)}{a - 1} + 1} = k$$

which can be transformed to this (by replacing $a$):

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{(x - 1) (b - 1)}{\frac{b*c}{b*c - c - b} - 1} + 1} + 
  \frac{1}{\frac{(x - 1) (c - 1)}{\frac{b*c}{b*c - c - b} - 1} + 1} = k$$

Is it possible to somehow remove those $b$ and $c$ and leave only $a$ in equation?

Comment: I doubt it.  Consider $a,b,c,k$ as constants and $x,y,z$ as variables.  The first two equations describe a line in three-space, and the third equation is some cubic surface, so we want to know where the line intersects the surface.  The last equation really has nothing to do with that.  It just gives some restrictions on the coefficients of the equation of the line.  We can use the last equation to eliminate one of $a,b.c$, but not two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If this were possible, then the value of $x$ would depend only by $a$, independently by the values of $b,c$.

But now, fix any value of $k$, and consider the two cases

1. $a=2, b=c=4$

your equation becomes
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\frac{3(x-1)}{1}+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{3(x-1)}{1}+1}=k $$
which gives you some solution $x_1$.

2. $a=2, b=3, c=6$

your equation becomes
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\frac{2(x-1)}{1}+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{5(x-1)}{1}+1}=k $$
which gives you *a different* solution $x_2 \neq x_1$.

Thus knowing $a=2$ in both cases cannot give you explicitely the value of $x$.